# ¿Cómo acceder al resultado de una promesa en React.js?

Tags: reactjs, jwt, async-await

Estoy creando las rutas privadas a la cual el usuario no podrá acceder si no tiene un token válido. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from 'axios';


const existToken = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('my-token');
    if(token) { //¿Hay token?
        const validateToken = async () => { //Si existe un token procedo a validarlo
            try{
                const {data} = await Axios.get(URI ,{headers:{'x-access-token' : token}});
                return data.authorization; //Contiene 'true' o 'false' dependiendo de si es encontrado
            }catch(error){
                console.log('Hay token pero es falso');
                return false;
            }
        }
        return validateToken(); //Retorno el resultado
    }else{
        console.log('No hay token');
        localStorage.removeItem('my-token')
        return false;
    }
};


const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Route 
            {...rest}
            render={props => 
            existToken() ? //Aquí quisiera recibir un boolean en vez de una promesa
                (<Component {...props} />) 
                : 
                (<Redirect to={'/'}/>)
            }
        />
    );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

El código ejecuta lo que tiene que ejecutar dependiendo de si el token existe, y si es válido o no. Pero no sé cómo hacer para acceder al resultado de la promesa (el `[[PromiseValue]]: '..'` ) para retornar ese boolean al `PrivateRoute`.Ya que por lo visto dentro de `validateToken()` no estoy pudiendo acceder a los return, sino que solamente al resultado de la promesa. 
¿Qué podría hacer? Cualquier sugerencia para mejorar el código son bienvenidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que poner la lógica del acceso dentro del componente y hacer uso del ciclo de vida de React para actualizar la variable `isAuth` (por ejemplo) una vez que te llega respuesta.

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    cons [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('my-token');
        if(token) { //¿Hay token?
            try{
                const {data} = await Axios.get(URI ,{headers:{'x-access-token' : token}});
                setIsAuth(data.authorization); //Contiene 'true' o 'false' dependiendo de si es encontrado
            }catch(error){
                console.log('Hay token pero es falso');
            }
        }else{
            console.log('No hay token');
            localStorage.removeItem('my-token')
            return false;
        }
    }, []);
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
            isAuth() ? //Aquí quisiera recibir un boolean en vez de una promesa
                (<Component {...props} />)
                :
                (<Redirect to={'/'}/>)
            }
        />
    );
}
```

**EDITED:**

Te comparto un ejemplo de cómo lo tengo hecho en mis aplicaciones:

```js
#containers/App.js

const App = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <ErrorBoundaires>
      <Suspense fallback={<LoadingBar className="redux-loading-bar" showFastActions />}>
        <Switch>{routesBoot()}</Switch>
      </Suspense>
    </ErrorBoundaires>
  </Router>
);
```

````js
# routesBoot.js

export default () => [
  <RouteWithLayout key="/" path="/" exact component={Home} layout={MainLayout} />,
  <RouteWithLayout key="alerts" path="/alerts" component={Alerts} layout={MainLayout} />,
  <RouteWithLayout key="dashboard" path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} layout={MainLayout} />,
  <RouteWithLayout key="login" path="/login" component={Login} layout={PublicLayout} />
....
];


```js
#RouteWithLayout.js

const RouteWithLayout = ({ layout, component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => createElement(layout, props, createElement(component, props))} />
);
````

En mi caso tengo un componente wrapper para cambiar el Layout

```js
#MainLayout.jsx

const MainLayout = ({ location, history, children }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    sendPage(location.pathname);
  }, [location.pathname]);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AppBar
        pathname={location.pathname}
        push={history.push}
        color="secondary"
        title="GBPD"
        subtitle="Buscamos desaparecid@s"
      />
      <LoadingBar className="redux-loading-bar" showFastActions />
      <MainLayoutStyled>
        <Menu />
        <SnackBar />
        <div className="App">
          <div className="App-header">{children}</div>
        </div>
        <HomeFooter />
      </MainLayoutStyled>
      <ModalRoot />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default AuthWrapper(MainLayout, ['user']);
```

Aqui `children` es el componente final que quieres renderizar y la parte en la que checkeo la autenticación es en el export de este mismo componente con otro wrapper sobre el Layout.

```js
#AuthWrapper.js

function AuthWrapper(WrappedComponent, permissions) {
  class AuthWrapper extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      const { validateToken, authenticated, history } = this.props;
      const token = localStorage.getItem('wc-token');

      if (!token) {
        history.push('/login');
      } else if (!authenticated) {
        validateToken(token);
      }
    }

    render() {
      const hasAccess = this.props.userPermissions.some(hasPermission(permissions));
      if (!hasAccess) {
        return <NotAllowed />;
      }
      if (!this.props.authenticated) {
        return <LoadingBar className="redux-loading-bar" showFastActions />;
      }

      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  AuthWrapper.propTypes = {
    authenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    validateToken: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.shape({
      push: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    })
  };

  const mapStateToProps = ({ auth: { authenticated }, user }) => ({
    authenticated,
    userPermissions: user.local.permissions
  });

  const mapDispatchToProps = { validateToken: validateUserToken };

  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AuthWrapper);
}

export default AuthWrapper;
```

Espero te sirva, cualquier duda comenta!

Comment: ¡Es buenísimo!.. ¡Claro!, en PrivateRoute se retorna jsx, no me dí cuenta que se lo podría tratar como un componente y crear estados. Tomé el ejemplo de [https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow], pero era ejemplo único, no encontré más formas de uso. Voy a implementarlo y te comento si funcionó, muchas gracias.
De todas formas te hago otra pregunta, ya que en reacttraining no encontré la explicación: ¿qué es `rest` dentro de los parámetros de `PrivateRoute` y dentro del componente `Route`?

Comment: Vale, imagina que el componente X recibe como props `prop1, prop2, prop3`, en ese mismo componente usas únicamente prop1 pero quieres pasar prop2 y prop3 al hijo, tendrías 2 opciones o pasar ambas o, en vez de eso, recibir `prop1, ...restoDeProps`, ésta ultima puedes nombrarla como quieras ya que recogerá en ella todas las props que no hayan sido destructuradas, en este caso, pasarias al hijo {...restoDeProps} que equivaldría a pasar prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2} al hijo

Comment: Cuando defino mis rutas privadas utilizo (ejemplo): 
`<PrivateRoute path="URI" Component={MyComponent}/>`. 
1) El componente `PrivateRoute` recibe como props `path` y `component`, ¿es así?;
2) `PrivateRoute` destructura las mismas y,  ¿la prop `Component` se guarda en `component` y `path` (junto a todas las props que existan) se guarda en `...rest`?
3) En el `return`, se devuelve un componente `<Route/>` al que se la el `path` (que sería `..rest`) , ¿es así?
4) Y por último, lo que no entiendo es `render`, ¿Es una prop que se le pasa `Route`?

Comment: Creo que te la haría más fácil si me pondrías un ejemplo del mismo código pero utilizando clases.. ¿Podrías?